# HTTP request in an interval doesn't work Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

I'm working on Angular 10 with function of checking connectivity by keep sending a request to the server every 5 seconds.

The problem is the request doesn't really sent out, it just keep `console.warn` every 5 seconds.

The problem only occurs when response responded with `status 200`, if responded with `status 404`, it works. Once it responded with `status 200`, it won't send any HTTP request in every 5s and just print out the previous http request's data.

PS: I'm testing on localhost server

Here is my code

```
checkConnection(): Subscription {
    return interval(2000)
      .subscribe(
        x => {
          this.httpService.testConnectivity().subscribe(
            data => console.warn(`Success: ${data}`),
            error => console.warn(`Error: ${error}`),
            () => console.warn("Completed")
          )
        }
      );
}
```

The `testConnectivity` function as below

```
testConnectivity(): Observable<any> {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      return this.http
        .get(`${this.url}/api/testconnection`, { observe: 'response' })
        .pipe(
          catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
The problem is the HTTP request was cached by the browser.

In order to making a refresh request. Simply add `?x` where x is some unique number after the url (Eg: `http://localhost:3000/api/testconnection?0`) on every request.